# spring mvc no xml configuration 404 error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, model-view-controller

I am trying to develop a simple Spring MVC with no XML application .its basically show a simple home page. I am using tomcat on JetBrains IDE for development and problem is that when I run it on tomcat I see 404 error this is url  `http://localhost:8080/MySpringSecurityApp_war/`

this is a controller

```
@Component
public class DemoController {
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String showHome(){
        return "home";
    }
}
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.luv2code.springsecurity.demo")
public class DemoAppConfig  {
    //define a bean for view resolver
    @Bean
   public ViewResolver viewResolver(){
      InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver=new InternalResourceViewResolver();
      viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
      viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
      return  viewResolver;
    }
}
```

```
public class MySpringMvcDispatcherServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[0];
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] {DemoAppConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }
}
```

this is error log

```
9-Jun-2020 13:32:07.511 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound.noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/MySpringSecurityApp_war/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
09-Jun-2020 13:32:07.604 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound.noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/MySpringSecurityApp_war/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

this is also how my project structure

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a resource path if you adding something into your URL (after host part basically in your case `MySpringSecurityApp_war`)  you are calling `localhost:8080/MySpringSecurityApp_war/` but you didn't define the resource path anywhere so I guess what you need to do is either add `@RequestMapping("/MySpringSecurityApp_war/")` at class level or just call `localhost:8080/` without any resource path
You can also use `@RestController` in place of `@Component`.

I hope it will work.

Comment: thanks. I noticed i need to replace Component with Controller